# Problem with SPFx TypeScript json.value.map(k,i) & query via getuserbyid()

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, typescript, sphttpclient, map

Firstly I'll start with extra question:

I'm trying to get data by `_api/web/getuserbyid()` API call in code.
Do You guys know why there is no option for filtering by query for specific data? I mean by:

```
_api/web/getuserbyid(6)/items?$select=Title
```

But know going to the subject of `.map` (the code is shown below) I've got error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

interface

```
export interface ISponsorData{
  Title: string;
  UserPrincipalName: string;
}
```

declaration

```
private _sponsorData: ISponsorData[] = [];
```

f

```
private _getSponsorDetails(): Promise<any[]>{
    var _sponsorURL = `https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/SC/_api/web/getuserbyid(6)`;

    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(_sponsorURL,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{value: ISponsorData[]}> => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json: {value: ISponsorData[]}) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
        return this._sponsorData=json.value.map((k,i) =>({
          Title: k.Title,
          UserPrincipalName: k.UserPrincipalName
        }
        ));
      });
    }
```

for now log below is set as undefined (no suprise here)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
```

When I'm printing to the console `console.log(response.json());`, I've proper response from the API call:

```
[PromiseValue]]: Object
@odata.context: "https://MY.sharepoint.com/sites/SC/_api/$metadata#Users/$entity"
@odata.editLink: "Web/GetUserById(6)"
@odata.id: "https://MY.sharepoint.com/sites/SC/_api/Web/GetUserById(6)"
@odata.type: "#SP.User"
Email: "name@MY.onmicrosoft.com"
Expiration: ""
Id: 6
IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser: false
IsHiddenInUI: false
IsShareByEmailGuestUser: false
IsSiteAdmin: true
LoginName: "i:0#.f|membership|name@MY.onmicrosoft.com"
PrincipalType: 1
Title: "Name LastName"
```

I've found on stackoverflow, that the error might be caused if values were null, but they are not. What possible is wrong with my approach?
I've used `=json.value.map((v,i) =>({` before and it is working, and it was also for spHttpClient Call.

Answer (score 1):

`GetUserById` does not return a collection (array), `map` is for iterating. [GetUserById](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn499819%28v%3Doffice.15%29) returns just a object.

You access the properties with; `json.value.Title`

For using `$select` you can do: `https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/SC/_api/web/getuserbyid(6)?$select=Title,UserPrincipalName`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndersAune